# Python - values only being used if they are after the initial in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a program that finds likely friends by finding similarities in user scores in different topics:

```
def similarity(user,d_list):

user_data=()
user_score=[]



for item in d_list:
   if user in item:
       user_data=item[1]


   if item[0]!=user :
        local_score=0


        local_score=sum(a*b for a,b in zip(user_data,item[1]))          
        user_score.append(local_score)

print user_score 





return
```

When using:

```
ratings=(("mark",[4,8,0,7]),("bob",[3,6,9,1]),("jim",[11,4,6,3]),("steve",[22,19,1,0]))
```

As the d_list and "mark" as the user, the program works as expected, giving:

```
[67, 97, 240]
```

When bob is used, the comparison with mark is set to 0.

```
[0, 114, 189]
```

When steve is used the set is just zeros. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The calculation was still nested inside the first iteration through d_list.

```
def similarity(user,d_list):

user_data=()
user_score=[]



for item in d_list:
   if user in item:
       user_data=item[1]


for item in d_list:

    if item[0]!=user :
        local_score=0


        local_score=sum(a*b for a,b in zip(user_data,item[1]))          
        user_score.append(local_score)

print user_score 





return
```